# Windows Phone Emulator 7.1 doesnt open

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, winapi

I successfully installed windows phone SDK 7.1 in my pc but when I tried to open the Windows phone emulator it shows an error says "Windows phone emulator is not supported on this computer bcoz this computer does not have the required graphics processing unit configuration. An XNA framework game or page will not function without a graphics processing unit. A silverlight Application may run, but with reduced functionality"

I have OS which is win7 ultimate (32-bit), 1-GB DDR-II ram, Intel Dual Core Processor; I know that it needs 3GB ram but I have seen it in a forum that it can also be installed with 1-GB of ram & I don't think there is a problem of ram here but of graphics. I am a newbie in this stuff but desperately wants to learn to create apps please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems with your configuration:

1. Your amount of RAM is too limited. I tried but never managed to start the emulator on a 1GB device, so consider yourself lucky if you succeed. You should upgrade to at least 2GB.
2. Your GPU is too old. You should be able to run Silverlight applications (if you get past the issue mentionned in point 1.), but you'll never be able to run XNA applications.

Note: Even if you can't start the emulator, you can still debug the applications by deploying them to a real device.

Comment: I don't have a windows phone so therefore I cannot debug the applications by deploying them to real device. So what should I do to develop apps or run XNA applications? And even if I change my ram from 1GB to 3GB (add 2GB more) will I be able to use SDK without any problem?

Comment: @HrishikeshSomchatwar No matter what you do, if you don't change your GPU you won't be able to use the emulator to run XNA applications.

Comment: so what should be done to use SDK 7.1 and start making apps without any problem? Change my ram from 1-GB DDR-II to 3-GB DDR-II, and Get a Graphics card? what more? Will it be enough? And does the DDR-II and DDR-III thing will affect? or It doesnt matter?

Answer (score 0):

You system configuration is limited. Windows phone 7 requires minimum 2 GB RAM. But better to hve 3 GB or more, because in 2 GB too the emulator wont work smoothly. Sometimes it will hang or take so long to load. And also I think you should upgrade your processor too for smooth working with windows phone emulator.

Thanks.